# jQuery calling function on page load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute this function:

```
    function scrollDesign () {
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#design').offset().top }, 1000);
        });
    };
```

in this way:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(scrollDesign);
});
```

but nothing happens.

This function separately works well:

```
        $( window ).scroll(function() {
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#design').offset().top }, 1000);
        });
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why do You call the function `scrollDesign` this way? Where have You found tutorial or something?

Comment: it's just example, i actually call it like that:
    var options = [
      {selector: '#home', offset: 1, callback: "scrollDesign()" },
    ];
    Materialize.scrollFire(options);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(scrollDesign);
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    scrollDesign();
});
```

This first code sample is not doing anything other than wrapping a function in a jQuery selector. It is not invoking it.

Comment: or just `$(function() {$(window ).scroll(function() {
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#design').offset().top }, 1000);
        });});`

Comment: Yes that should also be ok

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to call a function in JavaScript (and many other languages):

```
function_name()
function_name(argument)
function_name(argument, second_argument)
function_name(argument, second_argument, third_argument)
// And so on...
```

The documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

The `$()` is a short form for `jQuery()`. (The `$` is a common letter in JavaScript.) This function may produce very different results based on arguments.

The form `$(function_name)` is a short for
`$(document).ready(function_name)`
or
`jQuery(document).ready(function_name)`.

The documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/